# Can Oracle Database Sequence have a max value like 38 digits?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I am using Oracle 12.x DB and have a column with data type - NUMBER(38, 0) and would be populating this column from a Sequence. But I read the maximum value from a sequence would be 28 precision digits i.e. 10^28 -1 value.

1. Is there a way to generate a maximum of 38 digits value to populate the column mentioned above?
2. If Oracle sequence cannot go beyond 28 digits then WHY Oracle supports data type like NUMBER with 38 digits precision??

Thanks.

Comment: And why do you think that number columns can get values only from sequences? A valid question would be why sequences cannot go to 38 digits. But I have no answer to that.

Comment: A 70kg human body has approximately 7x10^27 (7e27) atoms. Unless you are cataloguing individual atoms or doing something at a similar scale then the requirement to have a sequence with more than 28 digits appears to be absurd. Why does it matter if there are 28 or 38 digits in a sequence when you are likely to reach other limiting factors before you reach the end of the sequence (i.e. lack of hard drive space or there are 3e15 nanoseconds in year so at 1-sequence value per nanosecond it would take 1e13 years to fill a 28-digit sequence).

Comment: @gsalem Sequence can be used as per needs to have a unique ID. Why not for NUMBER(38) ?

Comment: Even if you would store only **a single Byte** for every number of sequence 1*10^28 it would result in 100 Million Zettabyte. One Zettabyte is approximately the global yearly Internet traffic.

Comment: You can use a sequence to generate unique IDs for a number(38), who said you cannot. if you need to go beyond 10^28, then add a prefix to the sequence (e.g. rpad('1',29,'0')+seq.nextval will do (seq being your sequence name)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the limit of a sequence is 10^28-1. Oracle supports larger numbers because sequences aren't the only things to use the number data type. You'd have to ask Oracle why sequences don't go any higher than that.